# How to set up a multi-user text mode in Debian wheezy 7.6?

Tags: linux, command-line, debian, runlevel

I'd like to set up one of the available runlevels to work as a 'multi-user text mode' runlevel. Such mode available e.g. on CentOS.

Another example of what I need would be what you get when you add the `text` keyword in the GRUB editing mode and proceed with booting.

Here is what I tried and it didn't work for me:

```
sysv-rc-conf --level 3 gdm3 off
sysv-rc-conf --list gdm3          # Confirm that gdm3 is now off at runlevel 3

telinit 3    # Switch to runlevel 3
```

I'm stuck with a screen that shows up after I execute the `telinit 3` command. The message on the screen says `[....] Stopping GNOME [ ok ay Manager: gdm3.` and no command prompt appears.

The `update-rc.d -f gdm3 remove` command won't work for me (I haven't actually tried it) since I believe it will remove the ability to use GUI altogether. I want the GUI runlevel and a separate multi-user text mode runlevel to be present on the system at the same time.

Also I'm aware of runlevel 1 (single-user text mode) existence. That's not what I need.

The question again - how to set up a multi-user text mode in Debian wheezy 7.6?

Thanks